# Submenu not displaying on Chrome

Tags: html, css, submenu

Chrome won't display my submenu on the following domain:
http://www.putmanwoningonderhoud.nl/

I'm using Wordpress 4.5.3, with Avada 4.0.3.

I have tested on FireFox 47, IE 10/11 and Chrome 51. The latter of wich refuses to display my submenu. It appears as if it hides behind the slider. When removing the slider from the DOM it's visible, but it can't be clicked.

I have tried using z-index, display, opacity, and visibility-rules on multiple DOM elements but none of them seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `z-index:auto` to `z-index:10` to your class `.fusion-header-wrapper`

```
.fusion-header-wrapper{
   z-index:10 !important;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know about that but instead of comment you can edit his answer also...